# Android glow effect on 40+ textview objects

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to figure out the best way to reproduce a glow effect around text view object. The best glow comes from using a 9ppatch image from http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/ . The problem is i need to display 40+ textview objects on screen at a time. Is it advisable to use a 9patch image for them ? . I have tried making a XML drawable for background to reproduce a shadow effect but it does not look as natural as the 9 patch image( it has sharp breaks when the padding changes opacity) something like this -

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#107575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#207575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#307575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <solid android:color="#407575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:bottom="1dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"/>

        <solid android:color="#507575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#7575FF" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: yes, you can use nine patches even for 40+ text views

Comment: Perhaps you'd consider using android:shadowColor, android:shadowDx, android:shadowDy, android:shadowRadius; alternatively setShadowLayer() ?